# How to run a shell script with subshell as command line arguments by systemd

Tags: systemd

I have a shell script that accepts command line arguments expressed as output of other shell scripts, that is to say:

```bash
myscript1.sh -opt `myscript2.sh`
```

I need to launch this script by means of systemd

I tried to add this directive in the .service file

```ini
...
[Service]
...
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "myscript1.sh -opt `myscript2.sh`"
...
```

and the solution indeed works.

My question is the following: is it possible to launch directly the script `myscript1.sh` without using the `/bin/bash` command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with the documentation, see `man systemd.service`

> **`ExecStart=`** Commands with their arguments that are executed when this service is started. The value is split into zero or more command lines according to the rules described below (see section "Command Lines" below).

And then following the cross-reference

> **COMMAND LINES** This section describes command line parsing and variable and specifier substitutions for `ExecStart=` […and other…] options.
>
> Multiple command lines may be concatenated in a single directive by separating them with semicolons (these semicolons must be passed as separate words). Lone semicolons may be escaped as ";".
>
> […]
>
> **This syntax is inspired by shell syntax**, but only the meta-characters and expansions described in the following paragraphs are understood, and the expansion of variables is different. **Specifically, redirection using `<`, `<<`, `>`, and `>>`, pipes using `|`, running programs in the background using `&`, and other elements of shell syntax are not supported.**

So it becomes apparent that the `ExecStart=` option is not parsed by a shell but rather by a process that implements a very limited subset of shell code.

I'd use this variant of your code, which uses a simpler shell and the more modern replacement for backticks

```
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'myscript1.sh -opt $(myscript2.sh)'
```